# Heroku build fails because npm is missing

Tags: java, node.js, heroku, npm, terser

I am using terser as a minification step in a gradle task.
But heroku does not have the `npm` binary during the build.

This is what i tried

```
val installTerser = tasks.create<Exec>("installTerser") {
    commandLine("npm", "install", "-g", "terser")
}
```

Is there a way to install a executable into the repository,
so i can use it without the need for npm in heroku ?

Or how can i tell heroku that i need both java and nodejs tools ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the Node.js buildpack to your app by running:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add -i 1 heroku/nodejs
```

Then redeploy.

Comment: i did this but now heroku fails the build because it is not a nodejs Application, eg. files it expected are missing, can i just make npm available without heroku triggering a nodejs build ?

Comment: can you create an empty `package.json` in the root dir of your app? It could contain only `{}`